# При повороте сбрасывается таймер обратного отсчета

Tags: java, android

Есть таймер обратного отсчета на 10 секунд, по истечению времени открывается новое activity, однако при повороте устройства таймер сбрасывается, пытался сохранить значение секунд в int и использовать onSaveInstanceState(), но ничего не получилось (А мне нужно, что бы приложение можно было повернуть), помогите разобраться!
Вот код:

```
public void startTimer() {
    cTimer = new CountDownTimer(10000, 1000) {
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            mTimer.setText("" + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
        }
        public void onFinish() {
            mTimer.setText("done!");
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity2.class);
           /*Здесь реализация*/

            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    };
    cTimer.start();
}


public void cancelTimer() {
    if(cTimer!=null)
        cTimer.cancel();
}
```

Comment: вы, видимо, как-то не правильно сохраняли в onSaveInstanceState. Показывайте, как сохраняли, мы исправим.

Comment: при повороте устройства Activity создается заново, поэтому и сбрасываются значения. Для временного хранения значений в таких случаях действительно используется onSaveInstanceState, поэтому скорее всего причина в его реализации...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Скорее всего, вы только сохранили данные в методе `onSaveInstanceState`, но не восстановили их в методе `onRestoreInstanceState`:

```
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    //тут вы должны восстанавливать данные, сохранённые в методе onSaveInstanceState
}
```

Answer (score 0):

В `Manifest.xml` в активити пропиши параметр `android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"`

Comment: Это так же сохраняет ArrayList, который генерировался случайно